# How to host Simple Node JS express web app on Azure web app .Net stack

Tags: node.js, express, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, asp.net-4.8

I have a web app with following settings .

[image]

and want to run a node js express web app on the given configuration.

I have seen one of my colleague do it once but couldn't recall the settings.

Comment: How your are hosting your web app? Are you using Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio ?

Comment: Visual studio code